# How do I re-post from the PAGES to appear at HOME

Tags: publishing-page

Today was my first approach to sharepoint online (as an owner); we had only had 2 posts and I deleted them, as if I was un-posting them. 
So I have them at the PAGES (.aspx), but I don't find how to re-post them to the main page (not as homepage).
Thanks for your help,

Comment: Do you mean to publish them? so they are available to all?

Comment: Where is the `.aspx` page is stored in Pages/Site Pages? Is there versioning enabled on that particular library?